# What are the reasons for use static contextTypes = {} in react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand some code. Can you please explain to me what is the purpose of doing this static contextTypes = {}? Why we define it like so? What are the benefits?

```
static contextTypes = {
  product_id: PropTypes.number,
  size: PropTypes.number,
  loadRelatedProducts: PropTypes.func,
}
```

[image]

You can find full component code here -> https://jsfiddle.net/8hbyLopq/1/

---

**EDIT and information for developers from future:**

So I read docs and it is type-checking.

React docs says:

> PropTypes exports a range of validators that can be used to make sure
>   the data you receive is valid. In this example, we’re using
>   PropTypes.string. When an invalid value is provided for a prop, a
>   warning will be shown in the JavaScript console.

Questions about that:

1. This type-checking is for props that are comming from RelatedProducts component parent, yes? So it is checking if RelatedProducts parent is sending us product.id that is a number? If not there will be console log error shown, right?
2. It can also be used to check other inputs, because we are here importing a function loadRelatedProducts from a redux action, right?
3. Did I forget about something concerning the matter?

Comment: Have you read the relevant page on the official documentation? There is a pretty extensive explanation there. https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html. I'll be happy to explain more if you read it but still have questions.

Comment: React has a good documentation about [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Did you check it out?

Comment: I've read before https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html but was still confused. But https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html helped me to grasp on that. So @Chris  and Benny please check the edited version of my question and tell me if I got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. This type-checking is for props that are comming from RelatedProducts component parent, yes? So it is checking if RelatedProducts parent is sending us product.id that is a number? If not there will be console log error shown, right?

Correct. Yes to all the above.

> 2. It can also be used to check other inputs, because we are here importing a function loadRelatedProducts from a redux action, right?

Correct. It's quite evident from the code.

> Did I forget about something concerning the matter?

Not really. It's just type-checking to make sure you are getting context that meet the criteria:

- Are of the correct type (string/number/function, etc)
- Are passed in the first place if they are set to required with `isRequired`. Otherwise it's optional to pass it, as long as the type is correct **if** you pass it.